# Put classes in static arrays of other classes

Tags: python, arrays, class, static

This is a very specific problem, and is sort of tricky to explain. but here's a part of my code:

```
class Type:
    color      = [168, 168, 120]
    weakness   = []
    resistance = []
    immunity   = []

#**************************************************************************
#Defines all types---------------------------------------------------------
#**************************************************************************        
class Normal(Type):
    color      = [168, 168, 120]
    weakness   = [Fighting]
    resistance = []
    immunity   = [Ghost]

class Fighting(Type):
    color      = [192, 48, 40]
    weakness   = [Flying, Psychic, Fairy]
    resistance = [Rock, Bug, Dark]
    immunity   = []

class Flying(Type):
    color      = [168, 144, 240]
    weakness   = [Rock, Electric, Ice]
    resistance = [Fighting, Bug, Grass]
    immunity   = [Ground]
```

Yes, these are the Pokemon types, these are only 3 of the 18 in my file but they're all essentially the same. What I'm trying to do is have all of these classes have these static arrays of other classes.

The problem is that the Fighting in the Normal.weakness array is giving an error because Fighting hasn't been declared yet. However the Fighting in Flying.resistance is fine because Fighting has been declared.

Is there an easy fix for this? The first thing I tried was making the classes look like this:

```
class Fighting(Type):
    def __init__(self):
        self.color      = [192, 48, 40]
        self.weakness   = [Flying, Psychic, Fairy]
        self.resistance = [Rock, Bug, Dark]
        self.immunity   = []
```

But then whenever I want to implement these classes I have to make an instance of them which is annoying.

I've thought about declaring all of the classes then defining all of the arrays like
    Normal.resistance = [Fighting]
But that seems like a bit of a hassle. I've also thought of making them all seperate files and importing them to each other, but I don't even know if that would work. If anyone could help me out here I would really appreciate it!

--Edit--

I ended up making it an enum with functions for getting the arrays, it makes more sense this way

Comment: Generally-speaking you wouldn't store arrays of classes (you're verging on metaprogramming there), you would store arrays of an identifiers like strings or enums and use these in your logic. Classes are for defining the behaviour of their object instances, not for explicit use in logic. Unless this is a Python idiosyncrasy that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Maybe define all the classes first, with empty lists. Then fill the class attributes with the required values.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class Type:
    @classmethod
    def classInit(cls):
            if not hasattr(cls, color):
                cls.color = [168, 168, 120]
                cls.weakness = []
                cls.resistance = []
                cls.immunity   = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.classInit()  #only does something the first time it is called
class Normal(Type):
    ...
class Flying(Type):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a folder (aka, package) named `species` ('type' is a reserved word in Python so I like to avoid using it in any form), and within the `species` folder you have a separate file (aka, module) for each species.

This way you can import the species specific to weakness, resistance and immunity for any given species with no problem.

If you don't like `species`, other general group-like words are `kind`, `category`, `variety`, `breed` and `classification`, to name a few off the top of my head.

#### Folder Example

```
/species
    __init__.py
    abstract.py (what you call `class Type` I would rename to AbstractSpecies)
    normal.py  (from . import Fighting, Ghost)
    fighting.py  (from . import ...)
    flying.py  (from . import ...)
```

#### File example (normal.py)

```
from .abstract import AbstractSpecies
from .fighting import Fighting
from .ghost import Ghost


class Normal(AbstractSpecies):
    color      = [168, 168, 120]
    weakness   = [Fighting]
    resistance = []
    immunity   = [Ghost]
```